# Trouble figuring SQL Count When Dates Overlap

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query a DB with reservations. Each reservation has a Start Date (start), End Date (end), and Type (type) and I feed a month (month)

I want to query the DB to get the # of each type of reservation within a given month. However I can't for the life of me get it to count only the reservations within a date range.

I already managed to get it to give me counts, by type, for all reservations. And also give me only reservations within the date range. But filtering by specific months and counting the type is proving difficult and Google hasn't gotten me anywhere.

My Current Attempt:

```
// Queries the database for currently scheduled reservations and counts by type
        DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, month, 1);
        DateTime lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        string query = $"SELECT type, " +
            $"SUM(CASE WHEN start >= '{firstDayOfMonth}' AND start < '{lastDayOfMonth}' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count " +
            $"FROM reservation " +
            $"GROUP BY type";
```

Any guidance would be helpful. How do I get it to only count what's in the date range?

Comment: Put the `start` range in a `WHERE ` clause between `FROM` and `GROUP BY`. Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE reservation` in the question (you can edit it).

Comment: `WHERE start <= {endofmonth} AND end >= {beginningofmonth}`

Comment: In addition you can change your `SUM(...)` to `COUNT(*)`